# Authlogic activation problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic, activation

Sorry if this question was asked before but I got trouble with authlogic when I try to create UserSession instance in rails console like  `` `UserSession.create! :login => 'blabla', :passw...' ``  I get:

```
Authlogic::Session::Activation::NotActivatedError: You must activate the Authlogic::Session::Base.controller with a controller object before creating objects
```

Rails version: 3.0.4

Maybe I missed something?
I'll be appreciated for any help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you have to add somthing like

```
Authlogic::Session::Base.controller = Authlogic::ControllerAdapters::RailsAdapter.new(self)
```

into your `config/environment.rb` or somewhere.

Hint taken from article
[Working with Authlogic in script/console](http://www.tatvartha.com/2009/09/working-with-authlogic-in-scriptconsole/)